# Uploading PDF files from the front-end

Tags: uploads, forms, front-end

I am working on a Wordpress site that has a custom front-end form for submitting posts. I need to add a field in the form to allow users upload a single PDF file along with the post. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done a simple function for that, but i allow all types of media. So this could be a start:

```
function insert_attachment( $file_handler, $post_id, $settpdf='false' ) {

  // check to make sure its a successful upload
  if ( $_FILES[$file_handler]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) __return_false();

  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/image.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/file.php' );
  require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin' . '/includes/media.php' );

  $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file_handler, $post_id );

  if ( $settpdf ) update_post_meta( $post_id,'_pdf_id', $attach_id );

  return $attach_id;
}
```

and then a input like: `<input type="file" name="uploaded_pdf">`

You can retrive the meta like this:

```
$pdf = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_pdf_id', true);
echo '<a href="'.$pdf.'"><?php __('Download PDF','mytheme'); ?></a>';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, I'll try it out. 
One more thing please, how can I display this particular attachment as a link for download when people are viewing the post?
Can I set it to be stored in a custom field? That way I can retrieve it using get_post_meta.

Thanks again.

Comment: See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Pontus. You guys are the best. 
It's really amazing that I could get so much assistance. I really appreciate it. 
Will let you know if the code works well for me.

Comment: Hi @Pontus, at the risk of sounding greedy, can you please take a look at this other question of mine?: [WordPress search via metadata](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10774547/wordpress-search-via-metadata/)
The initial code seems to be baffling everyone so I would like to implement the search form using wp_query as suggested by one of the commenters. What is your opinion? 

Any pointers or code sample would really be appreciated because I'm not so good at tweaking WP.